# web interface for server-to-server file transfer

Tags: linux, ftp, rsync, file-transfer

I'm looking for a way to transfer files between two servers. I currently `ssh` into one server and use `rsync` inside a `screen` session to initiate a transfer from the other host. This works, but I'm looking for a web interface to do the same thing.

I'm imagining something I can run on one machine that shows the local files and can connect to some other box, list the files, and transfer across. It'd be like an FTP client but the client machine would be the one serving the web application rather than the one running the browser (which is what https://www.net2ftp.com/ does).

I've searched for web-based ftp and rsync applications but can't seem to find anything. Does something like this exist?

Comment: @techie007 the accepted answer there is to use `scp` over `ssh`. I mentioned that I already use `rsync` over `ssh`; I'm looking for a web application to do a similar job.

Comment: Specific software recommendations are off topic here (plus they have their own stack exchange softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) but you may want to look into Pydio (works under a standard LAMP stack).

Comment: thanks! didn't know about softwarerecs and will look into pydio 8)